# Можно ли создать объект внутри объекта в одном классе php?

Tags: php, ооп, классы

Можно ли создать внутри одного **(строго одного, без использования дополнительных)** класса что-то вроде объекта внутри параметра? Т.е. чтобы в итоге было что-то похожее на $this->config->login, а не $this->config["login"] ?

Comment: можно...............\

Comment: более того, внутри login можно еще какой-нибудь объект создать.

Comment: И даже это не предел.

Comment: @u_mulder "Бесконечность не предел" (с) (Базз Лайтер)

Comment: еще можно рекурсивные ссылки сделать.

Comment: Вам случаем не динамический класс нужно сделать? Тогда смотрите [Mockery](https://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html), с его помощью это можно сделать.

Comment: В пхп такой синтаксис как в шарпе \ яве - не завезли, описать класс внутри описания другого класса запрещено :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков и слава богу))

Answer (score 1):

```
class Config {
    public $login = 'hello';
}

class Test {
    private $config;

    public function __construct(Config $config) {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function testMe() {
        return $this->config->login;
    }
}

echo (new Test(new Config))->testMe();
```

Comment: Не совсем вариант. Нужно все это провернуть в одном классе без использования дополнительных.

Comment: @Инопланетныйгость в вопросе ничего про это не было. В итоге не ясно зачем и что нужно

Comment: `$this->config = (object) ['hello' => 'world']`

Comment: но и правда суть вопроса не ясна с такими комментариями

Comment: В вопросе было указано "Можно ли создать внутри одного (строго одного) класса". Предполагал, что все понятно. Сейчас добавил еще более уточняющее условие.

Comment: @Инопланетныйгость внутри одного - результат в ответе. там же строго внутри одного....... уточняющее условие ни о чём, к сожалению, не говорит. Нужно более подробное описание примерно того что нужно и вообще, понимание, "зачем".  В целом можно json_decode делать рекурсивно (или по-другому привести массив к объекту, кастануть)

Comment: ну и приведите массив к object как написано выше, будет у вас `$this->config->login`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class Config {
    public $login = 'hello';
}

class Test {
    public $config;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->config = new Config();
    }
}

$test = new Test();
echo $test->config->login;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]